# Is there an unresponsive host in a known place on the net that can be used to test http timeout?

Tags: http, timeout

What the question says really - I want to see how my program responds to timeouts.  Any suggestions on the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can quite easily create such a server on your own computer.  this is CoffeeScript (nodejs):

```
http = require 'http'

srv = http.createServer (req, res) ->
  setTimeout (() -> res.end "still here?"), 3000000
srv.listen 8000
```